# How to run grails generate-controller from command line with maven?

Tags: maven, grails

I'm looking for a way to run "generate-controller" from the command line for a mavenized grails 2.1.0 project (ie. grails-maven-plugin 2.1.0). I have tried the following:

- `mvn grails:generate-controller` - when running this I get an error saying "java.lang.IllegalStateException: User input is not enabled, cannot obtain input stream". For some reason, grails appears to not be able to read from the console (to obtain the name of the domain class).

  - http://jira.grails.org/browse/MAVEN-172 describes this error; I tried both solutions mentioned here (deleting the grails project cache and running mvn clean) but neither solved the problem
- `mvn grails:exec "grails:generate-controller"` - this results in a `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptNotFoundException`

**Is there a way to specify the name of the domain class via command-line parameter** - ie. something like `mvn generate-controller -DclassName=my.domain.class.name`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessarily intuitive, but in general *mvn grails:help* is useful.

**For help about creating domain classes and controllers**

```
mvn grails:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=generate-controller
mvn grails:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=create-domain-class
```

**Sample domain class and controller**

**UPDATE per comments received** : If you happen to use MS Windows, please quote the

*-DdomainClassName* argument values below.

```
mvn grails:create-domain-class -DdomainClassName=com.example.Test
mvn grails:generate-controller -DdomainClassName=com.example.Test
```

[UPDATE]

Blatant advertising, but I will create a second video for Maven and Grails integration soon, as you're not the only one with similar questions. The first one can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqGN61hiciE), very generic and for starters.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +2 for the answer and the "here's where to help yourself" with `grails:help`. Missed that tiny note in the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/commandLine.html#antAndMaven)

Comment: For me worked command `mvn grails:create-domain-class -DdomainClassName="com.example.Test"`. Without `""` I had some errors in console ;) (Windows PowerShell, Grails 2.4.2, Maven 3.2.2)