# Grails test war creation error

Tags: eclipse, maven, grails, maven-2, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.1.4 and Maven Integration.

I created pom file for Grails project. I am running a goal like this from Eclipse:

```
mvn -Dgrails.env=test package
```

I am getting error like this:

```
Fatal error forking Grails JVM: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.grails.launcher.GrailsLauncher.launch(GrailsLauncher.java:150)
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.tools.ForkedGrailsRuntime.main(ForkedGrailsRuntime.java:168)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.grails.launcher.GrailsLauncher.launch(GrailsLauncher.java:144)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: User input is not enabled, cannot obtain input stream
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
```

Comment: Looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/14879898/1651233

Comment: I saw that page, it not helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you're seeing may happen once in a while, especially in Grails 2.1.x.

Run the command(*mvn -Dgrails.env=test package*) couple of times and you'll notice that your problem is intermittent, it cannot be reproduced all the time.

Setting the fork option to false in your *pom.xml* seems to 'fix' it, *in most cases*. It's probably a Grails bug for 2.1.x releases.

I haven't seen the issue yet in newer Grails versions.

Comment: I did grails clean , after i run "mvn -Dgrails.env=test package" it working fine.

The problem was solved.

Thanks you are my best friend.

Comment: Thanks Rimero, I will try your solution also.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same error after upgrading Grails from 2.2.1 to 2.2.4 . 
The issue was that the plugin directory was not cleared out and was clashing with the new plugins coming in. 
The solution is to delete all of the plugins in the project root/plugins directory and then run any grails or maven commands to reinstall the new set of plugins.